# jsRender List of Objects in data attribute

Tags: jsrender

I have list of objects.

Data is the list which has Name,Date,ZipCode and ContactDetails. Here ContactDetails is another list which has EmailId.

In the below code, i can get Name,Date and ZipCode. But, i could not able to get the EmailID. Please tell me how to get this.

```
<a href="#provider" 
  data-eventname="{{:Name}}" data-eventdate="{{:StartDate}}"
  data-zipcode="{{:Zipcode}}" data-email="{{ContactDetails.EmailId}}">
</a>
```

Data[0].ContactDetails[0].EmailId: I always want ContactDetails[0] index only. So, no need for loop here.

TIA.

Comment: <a href="#provider" class="open-popup-link" id="providerDetail" data-eventname="{{:Name}}" data-eventdate="{{:StartDate}}" data-zipcode="{{:Zipcode}}" data-email="{{ContactDetails.EmailId}}" >
       
    </a>

Comment: above one is my code.

Answer (score 0):

You have not got the `{{:` on the `{{ContactDetails.EmailId}}`.

It should be `{{:ContactDetails.EmailId}}`